# Compass Calibration problem

Tags: iphone

How to get the Direction from  Compass Calibration,
i used core location framework and don't know how to get north direction from the function:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading;
```

if anybody knows help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the method is the right. You can chosse between magnetic and true heading.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{
    float compassHeading_True = newHeading.trueHeading;
    float compassHeading_Magnetic = newHeading.magneticHeading;
}
```

If you want allow compass calibration, you have to implement this method:

```
- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager{
return YES;}
```